# What is the meaning of closed or on hold?

Tags: support, closed-questions, on-hold-questions

I found in front of some posts are written [closed] or [on hold]. What is the meaning of them and who writes them?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "who writes them"?

Comment: @Ataraxia: It's surely meant in the same way as "who wrote the question we are commenting upon?", but with a less obvious answer.

Answer (score 5):

The information you seek can be found [in this FAQ thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

For future questions about M.SE functionality, please ensure to look through this FAQ (accessible through the "help" link behind your name at the top of the page) before asking on meta.